# Extend a Pointer/Reference with additional information

Tags: architecture

I am writing a program that procedurally generates a maze as the player traverses through it. Each maze tile possibly has a north, east, south and west neighbor. I was thinking about storing each neighbor using a pointer/reference, but I also have to save the information whether a pathway is free (for future maze generation or simply player movement if the neighbor is already generated) or if it is blocked.

I have thought of the following approaches:

```
// 1. aggregate data in a new data type
struct Pathway {
    bool isFree;
    MazeTile* neighbor;
}
Pathway north = {true, nullptr}

// 2. store data paralelly
MazeTile* north = nullptr;
bool isNorthFree = true;

// 3. Use inheritance to create a blocked tile
MazeTile* south = new BlockedMazeTile();
```

Personally i would go with the first approach, but i have never seen that done before. The third one seems nice and easily extendable, but the solution is bound to the underlying maze design and cant be used as a general approach to this kind of problem imo.

So, which one of these solutions is the preferred one - and if none, what is the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, of course, but I would go with the first one.

It is better than the third one because you can unblock your maze tile without recreating class instance, if needed. Who knows, what can happen in your magic land tomorrow, right? It will be better to be flexible. Just in case ;)

Also, if possible, you can store maze tiles as an array, if your game area is more or less square. Then you will not need any references to neighbour tiles at all. Just the `blocked` flag or whatever signifying that there is an entrance to the next tile.

Comment: The only reason that i am not working with a multidimensional array is that i want to play around with the data structure this problem presents. In reality the maze will never be bigger than say 20x20, but i want it to scale nicely in theory.

Comment: @LucaFülbier I see ;) Well, depending on a programming language, sparse arrays can be used, for example, to handle scaling. But of course without knowing all the details, one cannot recommend something specific.

Comment: You could say that i am trying to reinvent half a wheel for learning purposes ;-)

Comment: @LucaFülbier I am not going to. Seriously, it's perfectly fine to reinvent the wheel, the square and the stick for learning purposes. I'm doing that all the way.

Answer (score 1):

I'd also suggest #1, but it's not as rare as you think for a graph-style data structure to store additional data into the edges linking the nodes.

Another thing you can do if you want to make this really tight is to have these edges (pathways) simply store indices to a `MazeTile` instead of a pointer. With indices you can store auxiliary data into the upper bits, e.g., indicating whether the path is blocked or whatever you need.

Edit:

As requested, here is the index-based solution in a little more detail. Let's say you do this:

```
class Pathway 
{
public:
    /// Creates a new pathway.
    Pathway();

    /// Sets the index of the neighboring maze tile/node.
    void set_maze_tile(int new_index);

    /// @return The index to the neighboring maze tile/node.
    int maze_tile() const;

    /// Sets whether the pathway is free or not.
    void set_free(bool val);

    /// @return True if the pathway is free.
    bool is_free() const;

private:
    int index;
};
```

To do this would require you to allocate those maze tiles into some contiguous memory block (ex: using `std::vector` or another dynamic array of some sort -- it can grow without invalidating the indices).

Now you can do something like this:

```
enum
{
    free_bit = 1 << (sizeof(int)*8 - 1),
    index_mask = ~free_bit
};

Pathway::Pathway(): index(0)
{
}

void PathWay::set_maze_tile(int new_index)
{
     const bool was_free = is_free();
     index = new_index;
     set_free(was_free);
}

int PathWay::maze_tile() const
{
     return index & index_mask;
}

void PathWay::set_free(bool val)
{
    if (val)
        index |= free_bit;
    else
        index &= ~free_bit;
}

bool PathWay::is_free() const
{
     return (index & free_bit) != 0;
}
```

It's a little ugly, low-level style code, and this interface is a boring getter/setter kind of design, but it'll squash your pathways from typically occupying about 16 bytes on 64-bit (accounting for usual structure padding/alignment) to a mere 4 bytes, and that should help not only reduce memory use but also get a little more speed (greater spatial locality, more adjacent pathways fitting into a cache line).

It does reduce your unsigned indexing range from 2^31 to 2^30 (allowing about a billion maze tiles). You can double that range to 2^31 by using `unsigned int` (though it's probably not worth the bother unless you actually intended to handle something close to that scale).

Comment: I don't understand the indices solution. Can you explain it a bit more in detail?

Comment: I never would have used a bit-mask for this kind of thing, but this is a great solution if memory is sparse. But i could definitely use the index-solution in my program if i tweak it a bit. Thank you for the elaboration ;-)

Comment: Cheers -- probably the bitwise solution is overkill or, at the very least, premature. But I noticed you seem to want to solve this problem in kind of a generalized way -- it might help to think of this as a generalized undirected graph representation in that case with nodes and edges linking them together, at which point a compact edge representation might actually start to become desirable.